# Logstash Filter Conditional Not Getting Applied

Tags: configuration, logstash, nxlog

I've got nxlog on my Windows servers shipping logs to Logstash (JSON-formatted).  I want to clone off the security events to a SIEM, so I added the logic to catch certain Windows Event IDs:

[image: Logstash Config]

Even though the "Windows Event Log" tag gets applied (via "add_tag"), the "Windows Security Event" is never added, even when I review the logs and find an EventID like 4624.

For reference here's the full plain-text logstash.conf:

```
input {tcp{port=>1514}}
filter {
        if "im_msvistalog" in [message] {
                json {source => "message"}
                mutate {add_tag => "Windows Event Log"}
                if [EventID]=="4688" or [EventID]=="592" or [EventID]=="4624" or [EventID]=="528" or [EventID]=="540" or [EventID]=="5140" or [EventID]=="560" or [EventID]==5156 or [EventID]=="7045" or [EventID]=="601" or [EventID]=="4663" or [EventID]=="567" { 
                        mutate {add_tag => "Windows Security Event"}
                }
        }
}
output {stdout{codec=>rubydebug}}
```

Edit: Here's what the output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventID is an integer, but you are testing it in a string comparison.  Try removing the quotes around the number in your if block.

Comment: @armani The completeness of your question with screenshots / verbatim output made it much easier to spot, thank you.